# blueimp multiple file uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using the `blueimp multiple file uploade`r and everything is working great. However in some cases i have to use a single file upload. Is there a option of some sort that i can trigger to disable the multifile part of the plugin?

**It is important that  the flow doesnt change.** So that i can keep using it but just easily can disable multiple files.

I do want to mention that i dont want to give an error if the maxx file number is exceeded. I just want to disable multiple files all together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That’s easy, just remove the `multiple` attribute on the input element.